# Android with REST-API: Verify APK signature

Tags: android, rest, digital-signature, android-keystore

Simple Question: How can I verify on the Server-Side, that the HTTP Request was made from an APK signed with my key?

I could get the Signatures via

`Signature[] sigs = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;`

but this does not stop the user from modifying the API and replacing that part of the code.

Comment: put your own signature(in code) in signed apk

Answer (score 0):

An .apk is a compile version of your code so the user cannot modify the code (in theory) so the signature should be unique.

Comment: The code can be modified by decompiling, modifying and then recompiling the app, which is possible with tools like dex2jar.

Comment: That's why I say "in theory"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot unless you control the entire system, including the hardware device (excluding transparent proxies). You can then encrypt the APK file.

Otherwise you get back to the age-old DRM problem.